# undefined method `last' for #<Hash:0x00007f303593d6d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workato

trying the below code in a custom sdk in Workato

```
poll: lambda do |connection, input, last_updated_at|
      per_page = 1
      last_updated_at = (last_updated_at || input['since']).to_time.utc.iso8601
      candidates = get("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers")
      last_updated_at = candidates.last["created"] unless candidates.blank?
```

Getting an error
undefined method `last' for #Hash:0x00007f303593d6d8 at line:

Comment: You need `candidates['data'].last["created"]` according to the [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list). That being said this will give you the last customer in the given data list but not necessarily the "last customer". The default limit is 10 so you would get the 10th customer in this case

Answer (score 3):

[There is no `Hash#last` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html). Hashes *do* keep their insertion order, but you should conceptually treat them as unordered. The concept of the "last" element of a `Hash` simply does not make sense.

Comment: In this case, I am assuming that the get api returns the list of customers (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list) ... If so, how to get the last customer in the list..

Comment: The link you posted says you get a dictionary, not a list, so it seems you assumed wrong.

Comment: @user6816447 the "list" is contained in the ["data"] property in the dictionary.